# Semantic UI for Cordova Apps?

Tags: cordova, mobile, semantic-ui

Is [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com) suitable for a mobile app with Cordova intended to run on all major mobile phones (android, iphone, windows phone)? Has anyone already tried this and is willing to share his experiences?

Comment: Which UI library did you end up using?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it in a container app such as Cordova, but it has integrated very well with Backbone. So, there is no clue for it to not work. Maybe try to limit css transitions and animations for rendering performance, and that would be good.

Semantic-UI seems to be available as NPM (and maybe Bower) packages : http://learnsemantic.com/guide/expert.html#prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

Semantic UI works with Cordova app although CSS for **.ui.grid** and other components doesn't work well on some devices due to lack of support for ***flex*** property.